# Is it a join in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

I have three tables.
The first table is:

```
Orders
======
Ordernumber  PK
CartID 
Field1
....
```

The second table is:

```
OrderDetails
============
Ordernumber PK
SKU         FK (with InventorySuppliers localSKU field)
Field-a
.....
```

The third table is:

```
InventorySuppliers
=================
SupplierID   PK
LocalSKU     FK (Orderdetails table with 'SKU')
Field-x
....
```

I want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ORDERS 
WHERE  ORDERS.CARTID = 11 
       AND INVENTORYSUPPLIER.SUPPLIERID = 155
```

My problem is that there is no direct relation between the two tables used in this query.
How can I write this query?

Comment: sorry, my bad, its in orders table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
JOIN orderdetails od ON o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
JOIN inventorySuppliers is ON is.localSKU = od.SKU
WHERE o.cartID = 11
AND is.supplierID = 155
```

Because there is no direct relationship between `orders` and `inventorySuppliers` tables records, you have to use the third table (`orderdetails`) to join them together.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema design is fatally flawed, because two different suppliers may use the same sku for different products. Your schema provides no way to know which record in the inventory suppliers the sku refers to.

Before you can do anything else with this sql, you need to change the schema to include supplierID in the order details records.

Comment: sorry for this...but its not mine..I am trying to create some scripts over Amazon manager named STONE EDGE and schema is theirs...:(